# Why the classification results are concentrated in one category in CNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I want to use `CNN` model in classification and the `num_classes` is `22`. I use the [example code](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network_raw.py) of TensorFlow directly.

The number of training samples is `16522`. All the pictures has a same shape `(50,52)`.

```
# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Convolution Layer
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Apply Dropout
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    # Output, class prediction
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
    # 1024 inputs, 22 outputs (class prediction)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, num_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
}
```

The following is my results.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, my predicted result (the first picture) is bad, and many categories are incorrectly predicted as `Fault 4`.

I use `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as my loss function, the losses have been falling, but the accuracy is also decreasing. In my opinion, the loss function is useless in this situation, which leads to overfitting.

Any suggestions for this situation?

Comment: What is the exact programming problem here? That a model works bad is not a programming problem by itself.

Comment: Seems like you are having a class balance problem: when your training data contains overwhelmingly many samples from certain classes, the model will likely to "guess" that class more. Google the following keywords for more info: `classification class balancing`, `oversampling`, `undersampling`, `class weighing`.

Comment: Actually, each class has the same number of samples.